# php function causes sql query to fail

Tags: php, sql, function, db2

So I have found that when using db2 sql is inside a php function it does not return any values.

It fails on `DB2_PREPARE($conn, $sql2);`

Where as if you execute this code outside of the function it does its job perfectly fine and returns all of the results.

Code:

```
        function getRooms(){
            $sql2 = ("SELECT * FROM WS_ASSETS_rooms");
                    $stmt2 = db2_prepare($conn, $sql2);
                     if ($stmt2) {
                            $result2 = db2_execute($stmt2);
                            if (!$result2) {
                                     return "exec errormsg: " .db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt2);
                            }

                            while ($row = db2_fetch_array($stmt2)) {
                                    echo "$row[1]";
                            }
                    } else {
                            return "exec errormsg: " .db2_stmt_errormsg($stmt2);
                    }
};
    echo getRooms();
```

This returns `"exec errormsg:"` and no error.

Comment: where is $conn defined and assigned? is it in scope within the function

Comment: check that, I think, `db2_prepare` function or `$conn` has not scope in the function.

Comment: Thanks, $conn was not in the scope. Cant believe I missed that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$conn` is not in scope.  You have to either pass the variable to the function (recommended) or use the `global` keyword.

**Passing the variable**

```
function getRooms($conn){
    // ...
}

echo getRooms($conn);
```

**Using global**

```
function getRooms(){
    global $conn;
    // ...
}

echo getRooms();
```